# ReactNative - KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a page with two inputs and a 'Next' button. I want to move my container up when keyboard is active so that the 'Next' button is also visible when the keyboard is open. I've used `KeyboardAvoidingView` but the content is not moving when the keyboard is active. What seems to be the issue here?

Here is my code

```
    <View style={{height: '100%'}}>

          <LinearGradient colors={['#29aae1', '#4bc1b6']} style={{height: '100%'}}>

                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    behavior="padding"
                    keyboardVerticalOffset={0}
                    style={{padding:10}}
                >

                        <ScrollView style={{height:'100%'}}>

                                <Text style={styles.signin_info}>Let's get you signed in. Provide your first name and last
                                    name.
                                    Do not
                                    worry, when you comment your real name won't be visible ;)</Text>


                                <Field label="First name" name="signUpFirstName" component={this.renderInput}/>
                                <Field label="Last name" name="signUpLastName" component={this.renderInput}/>



                            <TouchableOpacity block primary style={styles.nextBtn_active}
                                              onPress={Actions.signUp_email}><Text
                                style={{fontFamily: 'gotham', fontSize: 18, color: 'white'}}
                                allowFontScaling={false}>Next</Text></TouchableOpacity>

                        </ScrollView>

                </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        </LinearGradient>

   </View>
```

Comment: I think that you need to set `flex: 1` of the `KeyboardAvoidingView`

Comment: i've set it but to no effect

Comment: Try to set a red background colour... to be sure that it covers the whole screen... maybe the height or width is not correct. If it's necessary add `flex: 1` and to the parent View

Comment: yh i added a background color and it covers the whole screen.

Comment: Later I will try to create a demo and to reproduce the issue. Will let you know if I have a progress. For the moment I don't have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you already ScrollView inside KeyboardAvoidingView, consider using [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your `KeyboardAvoidingView` component is not `enabled` !!! `enabled` property is mandatory:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
   behavior="padding"
   keyboardVerticalOffset={0}
   style={{padding:10}}
   enabled          // <-- this property is required
>
```

See: [enabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview#enabled)

Comment: so also test with `behavior="position"` and see if it works at all !!! Also make sure your `KeyboardAvoidingView` is your outermost view component.

Comment: Enabled is equal to `true` by default.